# Jump to definition does not work on objects defined as property on window

Tags: emacs, tern

In my tern set up in emacs, this code works fine when I do `M-.` when my cursor is under the `foo` of `obj.foo()` (in the last line):

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = function() {
    return true;
};

obj.foo();
```

But when I do the same on the following, it says "No definition found."

```
window.obj = {};
obj.foo = function() {
    return true;
};

obj.foo();
```

I tried making each refernce to `obj` as `window.obj`. Doesn't seem to help. Am I missing something?

Comment: To be clearer, you might want to edit your question for typos.  For example: `util.foo`? And be specific about where you are using `M-.` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem is that you don't use **browser** JSON Type Definition which defines **window** object. Your **.tern-project** should look like this :

```
{"libs":["ecma5","browser"]}
```

I have tried without **browser** and I have the same problem than you. If I declare **browser**, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are saying that what doesn't work is to put the cursor on `window.obj` and hit `M-.`.  To find the corresponding definition, `M-.` needs to have it indexed in a `TAGS` file. If that has not been done then you are out of luck: it won't be recognized.

See the Emacs manual, node [`Tags`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags.html) and its children, particularly node [`Create Tags Table`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Create-Tags-Table.html).